# DataGridCheckBoxColumn does not update in MVVM when property is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two key booleans in an app I am working on to indicate whether an order is valid to be approved, and then if the order has been approved or not. What I want is for the checkbox to update on both columns when the value in the ObservableCollection's object changes so the user knows whether the order is ready to be approved and whether it has already been approved.

The values update in the model correctly and the approve button command in the viewmodel sets the approved boolean as expected, however I have not been able to get checkbox to update dynamically. Currently it only updates by changing to a different view and then changing back to the order view.

I am still learning data bindings and the MVVM model so some of what I have tried has been experiments. So far I have tried a couple of different things to try and get the behaviour I desire but none have worked. Here is the view model code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="US_Wholesale_App_V2.Views.SPSOrderView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:US_Wholesale_App_V2.Views"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:US_Wholesale_App_V2.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:US_Wholesale_App_V2.Models"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1100">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SPSLineVM}">
            <local:SPSLineView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:CustomerInfoVM}">
            <local:CustomerInfoView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" MinWidth="312"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0">
            <Button
                Content="Lines"
                Height="20"
                Width="75"
                Margin="5,5,5,10"
                Command="{Binding SPSNavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Lines"/>
            <Button
                Content="Shipping"
                Height="20"
                Width="75"
                Margin="5,5,5,10"
                Command="{Binding SPSNavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Shipping"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <DataGrid
            x:Name="OrderHeaderGrid"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            Margin="5"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding SpsData}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder, Mode=TwoWay}"
            CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="PO Number"
                    x:Name="PONumberCol"
                    Binding="{Binding PONumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Customer"
                    x:Name="CustomerCol"
                    Binding="{Binding Customer}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Retailer PO Number"
                    x:Name="RetailersPONumberCol"
                    Binding="{Binding RetailersPONumber}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="DC Code"
                    x:Name="DCCodeCol"
                    Binding="{Binding DCCode}"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                    Binding="{Binding IsValid, Mode=OneWay}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn
                    Header="Approve">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button
                                Content="Approve"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.ApproveButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedOrder}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn
                    Binding="{Binding IsApproved, Mode=OneWay}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <ContentControl
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SPSCurrentVM}"/>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In case it is useful here is the model's code as well. The RGLibrary project is just a library of common classes I need such as SQL connectors or FTP methods.

```
using RGLibrary;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace US_Wholesale_App_V2.Models
{
    public class SPSOrderModel : Observable_Object, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        private bool _IsApproved;
        private string _PONumber;
        private string _RetailersPONumber;
        private string _PODate;
        private string _ShipDate;
        private string _CancelDate;
        private string _POPurpose;
        private string _POType;
        private string _VendorNumber;
        private string _Customer;
        private string _DCCode;
        private string _DepartmentNo;
        private ObservableCollection<SPSLineModel> _Lines;
        private BillingCustomerModel _BillingInfo;
        private ShippingCustomerModel _ShippingInfo;
        private ShippingChargesModel _Charges;


        public bool IsApproved
        {
            get { return _IsApproved; }
            set { _IsApproved = value; }
        }
        public string PONumber
        {
            get { return _PONumber; }
            set { _PONumber = value; }
        }
        public string RetailersPONumber
        {
            get { return _RetailersPONumber; }
            set { _RetailersPONumber = value; }
        }
        public string PODate
        {
            get { return _PODate; }
            set { _PODate = value; }
        }
        public string ShipDate
        {
            get { return _ShipDate; }
            set { _ShipDate = value; }
        }
        public string CancelDate
        {
            get { return _CancelDate; }
            set { _CancelDate = value; }
        }
        public string POPurpose
        {
            get { return _POPurpose; }
            set { _POPurpose = value; }
        }
        public string POType
        {
            get { return _POType; }
            set { _POType = value; }
        }
        public string VendorNumber
        {
            get { return _VendorNumber; }
            set { _VendorNumber = value; }
        }
        public string Customer
        {
            get { return _Customer; }
            set { _Customer = value; }
        }
        public string DCCode
        {
            get { return _DCCode; }
            set { _DCCode = value; }
        }
        public string DepartmentNo
        {
            get { return _DepartmentNo; }
            set { _DepartmentNo = value; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<SPSLineModel> Lines
        {
            get { return _Lines; }
            set { _Lines = value; }
        }
        public BillingCustomerModel BillingInfo
        {
            get { return _BillingInfo; }
            set { _BillingInfo = value; }
        }
        public ShippingCustomerModel ShippingInfo
        {
            get { return _ShippingInfo; }
            set { _ShippingInfo = value; }
        }
        public ShippingChargesModel Charges
        {
            get { return _Charges; }
            set { _Charges = value; }
        }

        public string Error
        {
            get
            {
                var errorMsg = new StringBuilder();
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DepartmentNo))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("The department number for this order cannot be blank");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PODate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("You must enter a purchase order date");
                else if (!DateValidate("PODate", PODate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("The PO date format must be MM/DD/YYY");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CancelDate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("You must enter a cancellation date");
                else if (!DateValidate("CancelDate", CancelDate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("The cancellation date format must be MM/DD/YYY");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ShipDate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("You must enter a shipment date");
                else if (!DateValidate("ShipDate", ShipDate))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("The shipment date format must be MM/DD/YYY");
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DCCode))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("You must enter a DC code");
                if (Lines.Any(p => !p.IsValid))
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("You must correct all errors in the purchase order lines, or remove any lines with errors");
                if (SumDispatch(Lines) < 1)
                    errorMsg.AppendLine("The total dispatch quantity must be at least 1");
                return errorMsg.ToString();
            }
        }

        public bool IsValid
        {
            get
            {
                bool check = true;
                if (IsHeaderValid == false)
                    check = false;
                if (BillingValid == false)
                    check = false;
                if (ShippingValid == false)
                    check = false;
                if (ChargesValid == false)
                    check = false;
                if (LinesValid == false)
                    check = false;
                return check;
            }
        }

        public bool BillingValid
        {
            get
            {
                if (BillingInfo != null)
                    return BillingInfo.IsValid;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public bool ShippingValid
        {
            get
            {
                if (ShippingInfo != null)
                    return ShippingInfo.IsValid;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public bool ChargesValid
        {
            get
            {
                if (Charges != null)
                    return Charges.IsValid;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public bool LinesValid
        {
            get
            {
                bool check = true;
                if (Lines.Any(l => l.IsValid == false))
                    check = false;
                return check;
            }
        }

        public bool IsHeaderValid
        {
            get
            {
                bool check = true;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PODate))
                    check = false;
                if (!DateValidate("PODate", PODate))
                    check = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CancelDate))
                    check = false;
                if (!DateValidate("CancelDate", CancelDate))
                    check = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ShipDate))
                    check = false;
                if (!DateValidate("ShipDate", ShipDate))
                    check = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DCCode))
                    check = false;
                if (Lines.Any(p => !p.IsValid))
                    check = false;
                if (SumDispatch(Lines) < 1)
                    check = false;
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DepartmentNo))
                    check = false;
                return check;
            }
        }

        public string this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                string result = null;
                if (name == "PODate")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PODate))
                        result = "You must enter a date";
                    else if (!DateValidate("PODate", PODate))
                        result = "Date format must be MM/DD/YYY";
                }
                if (name == "CancelDate")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CancelDate))
                        result = "You must enter a date";
                    else if (!DateValidate("CancelDate", CancelDate))
                        result = "Date format must be MM/DD/YYY";
                }
                if (name == "ShipDate")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ShipDate))
                        result = "You must enter a date";
                    else if (!DateValidate("ShipDate", ShipDate))
                        result = "Date format must be MM/DD/YYY";
                }
                if (name == "DCCode")
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DCCode))
                        result = "You must enter a DC code";
                }
                return result;
            }
        }


        private static bool DateValidate(string sender, object value)
        {
            bool check = true;
            if (sender == "PODate" || sender == "CancelDate" || sender == "ShipDate")
            {
                string _date = value.ToString();
                string _expression = @"(([0]\d)|(11|12))\/(([012]\d)|(30|31))\/(20)\d{2}";
                Regex _Regex = new Regex(_expression);
                Match _match = _Regex.Match(_date);
                if (!_match.Success)
                    check = false;
            }

            return check;
        }

        private static int SumDispatch(ObservableCollection<SPSLineModel> lines)
        {
            int dispatchQty = 0;
            foreach (SPSLineModel line in lines)
            {
                dispatchQty += line.DispatchQty;
            }
            return dispatchQty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming your view is bound to the `SPSOrderModel` class it lacks `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. The view doesn't get notifications about properties' changes and will always retain the initial values.

Comment: @max the SPSOrderModel class inherits from the Observable_Object class, which has the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. Do I need to implement an OnPropertyChanged() event for the two boolean fields I want updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As max mentioned on the question I need to implement a PropertyChanged event on the IsApproved and IsValid fields. For IsApproved this was fairly simple, as I could reuse the event from the inherited Observable Object class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RGLibrary
{
    public abstract class Observable_Object : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }

        #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        #region Debugging Aides

        /// <summary>
        /// Warns the developer if this object does not have
        /// a public property with the specified name. This
        /// method does not exist in a Release build.
        /// </summary>
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public virtual void VerifyPropertyName(string propertyName)
        {
            // Verify that the property name matches a real,
            // public, instance property on this object.
            if (TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)[propertyName] == null)
            {
                string msg = "Invalid property name: " + propertyName;

                if (this.ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName)
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                else
                    Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether an exception is thrown, or if a Debug.Fail() is used
        /// when an invalid property name is passed to the VerifyPropertyName method.
        /// The default value is false, but subclasses used by unit tests might
        /// override this property's getter to return true.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual bool ThrowOnInvalidPropertyName { get; private set; }

        #endregion // Debugging Aides
    }
}
```

So the implementation for IsApproved in the SPSOrderModel class is thus:

```
        public bool IsApproved
        {
            get { return _IsApproved; }
            set { _IsApproved = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsApproved"); }
        }
```

I'll edit this response once I have an answer for the IsValid property, as that is a read only property and trying to add OnPropertyChanged to it causes a stack overflow error.